# .htaccess RewriteRule key as folder and then value

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to make a RewriteRule.

I have the next URL 'https://sample.com/post.php?post=ABC123' and I tried to redirect with this 'https://sample.com/post/ABC123'

I just made one rule which redirects without '/post/', only the value:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)$ post.php?post=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+)/$ post.php?post=$1
```

How I can make the first rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this rule as your first rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)/?$ post.php?post=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# other rules go below
```

Comment: Well, i try that and not work, when i write in the URL 'https://sample.com/post/ABC123' is giving me an 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Comment out `Options -MultiViews` line and retest, rule works fine on my Apache

Comment: Possibly is my server problem, because without rules is giving me 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Yeah, it was my server, i just change post.php to posts.php and try your code, and work perfectly, Thanks a lot

Comment: But now i have a different problem, all documents like Styles, JS files is redirecting with the /post/ and not loading on the page

Comment: For that, you can add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ $1.php [NC]

RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ post.php?post=$1[QSA,L]
```

Comment: No, is not working, same problem '500 Internal Server Error'